# В переменную добавил input, хотел использовать данные из переменной а python не даёт

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-error

```
input("Если вы хотите дед инсайднутся, нажмите ENTER")
val = input("Введите задержку в секундах: ")
print("1000 - 7 = 993")
time.sleep(val)
```

При попытке взять данные из переменной в строке `time.sleep(val)` python выдаёт следующую ошибку:
TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)

Я пробовал все что мог

Comment: Попробуйте еще `time.sleep(int(val))`

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: Не могли бы пометить вопрос закрытым? И какие были попытки?

Comment: @DaLadno, на stackoverflow нет понятия "вопрос закрыт" в смысле "вопрос решен". Вопрос условно считается решенным, если у него есть ответ с положительным рейтингом. Специально как-то "помечать закрытым" не нужно.

Comment: @insolor его по идее удалят, т.к отрицательный рейтинг. Но пока он будет висеть как некоторые.

Comment: @DaLadno может удалят, а может и нет (например, если будет ответ с положительным рейтингом). В целом - я не вижу с этим вопросом каких-то особых проблем.

Answer (score 0):

У тебя val строка, а sleep принимает число.

```
input("Если вы хотите дед инсайднутся, нажмите ENTER")
val = int(input("Введите задержку в секундах: "))  # int()
print("1000 - 7 = 993")
time.sleep(val)
```